# Apply A Function to All Links on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have my all links on page like this :

```
<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
```

But Now I Want All Links With Following OnClick Function like this:

```
<a onclick="show();" href="http://example.com">Example</a>
```

can any one tell me jquery or javascript code to add above function to all links on body, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some answers have suggested to use jQuery's `click()` function. That's alright as long as you don't expect to add new links dynamically using javascript.

This click handler will bind on the `<body>` element, and fire whenever a `<a>` element inside it is clicked. The advantage with this over `$('a').click(...)` is that all `<a>` tags don't need to be present on page load:

```
$(function () {
  $('body').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    show();
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lubf6gjw/2/

**EDIT:** Here's how to do it with pure javascript:

```
document.querySelector('body')
.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if(event.target.tagName === 'A') { 
        event.preventDefault();
        show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pymwsgke/1/

Comment: but this is not working i have added your suggested code inside script tag in header but nothing is happened to html links

Comment: I presume the links just take you to another page as usual? Then you need to prevent the default event handler. I updated the example.

Comment: i have attached code pen link, you can see that its not working, can you please suggest solution by looking at code...
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LErPEM

- in result there are 2 button one is demo with onclick working fine with loader, but other button is demodynamic and not working and has not onclick function included in results

Comment: I noticed I had written `body` instead of `'body'`, which made it not work. I updated it and added a fiddle you can try.

Comment: i have checked by inspecting element and it is still not including onclick function to link , i have also attached my source code codepen link , you can check, thanks

Comment: It is not supposed to include any onclick function on the link. That's not how it works :)

Comment: but can you please tell me how to include onclick function on the link, thanks

Comment: My answer runs the onclick function on click. Here's an updated version of your codepen using pure JS method: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbyewR

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    $("a").click(function(){
        show();
    }
});
```

If you want to prevent the browser from following the href, you can just add a preventDefault call

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        show();
    }
});
```

---

Note that this will not actually append the `onclick=` to the `<a>` tags. If you want to do that, you can do it this way:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("onclick", $(this).attr("onclick")+";show();");
});
```

Comment: won't prevent href from being followed immediately by browser

Comment: @charlietfl that's not what OP asked for. All he wanted was to apply a function to each anchor.

Comment: just pointing it out since browser will somewhat ignore function and open href, or in other words user won't see what function does likely

Comment: that can be fixed with a preventDefault call.

Comment: but this is not working i have added your suggested code inside script tag in header but nothing is happened to html links

Comment: @AliveNick It will not actually *append* the onclick to the HTML. It will simply fire the JavaScript event when you click on the link.

Comment: yeah david but that is not working but following one is working, but this one is not opening any links after click, can you fix the following code:
document.querySelector('body')
          .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            if(event.target.tagName === 'A') { 
              event.preventDefault();
              show();
            }
          });

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Js

```
 function show (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
  // do somethink
}
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for(var a = 0; a < anchors.length; a++) {
     anchors[a].addEventListener("click",show,false)
}
```